# Wapiti outdated version of python-requests

Tags: system-installation, vmware-workstation

wapiti Wapiti-2.3.0 (wapiti.sourceforge.net)
Error: You have an outdated version of python-requests. Please upgrade

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! ;-) I'm sorry and, please, blame it on me: I'm confused and confusing...  But...  *What's your question???* :/

Answer (score 2):

Your python-requests module is too old, [wapiti uses python2.7](https://github.com/m4rkw/env/blob/master/bin/wapiti), so please update the requests module with the following command in your terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python-requests
```

You can check the module version in python with:

```
user@ubuntu:~$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Dec 18 2014, 19:10:20) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import requests
>>> requests.__version__
'2.2.1'
>>>
```

Comment: Python 2.7.3 (default, Mar 13 2014, 11:03:55) 
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

Comment: /root/Desktop/wapiti-2.3.0

Comment: @karim hi, I'm not sure what's the meaning of your comments here, does updating requests module works for you?

Answer (score 0):

**In order to work correctly, Wapiti needs :**

- Python 2.x where x is >= 6 (2.6, 2.7...)
- python-requests v1.2.3 or more ( http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/ )
- BeautifulSoup ( http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/ )
- python-xml

Source:http://wapiti.sourceforge.net/README